# PHP Cart with Object Oriented PHP

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I am developing a simple system of sample products with Object Oriented PHP, very simple thing. So far, no problem, but I have to create a button that adds a product code recorded in the database to a form in the sidebar. I do not know to develop a shopping cart with OO PHP, and codes that I find always give error because of the call of the database, or when the data list. I've been thinking of doing for JS, any help?

sorry my bad english

Comment: [Tutorial: Building a shopping cart in PHP](http://www.qualitycodes.com/tutorial.php?articleid=25&title=Tutorial-Building-a-shopping-cart-in-PHP)

Comment: i have a greate tutorial in french that can help you ,code is clear , do you want it ?

Comment: OK thanks. well, I have several products and on each a button to "add to quote" and need each time the button is clicked it will take the code that product and place in a field, without losing the previous one. Just as a simple shopping cart, but instead of prices and quantities, only need to list the codes of the products that the user clicked to add. But I'm not a good programmer, I made a simple system of registration of products but I can not make a simple shopping cart with the system I developed.

Comment: it's a video of more than 1hour but it's good http://www.grafikart.fr/tutoriels/php/panier-php-session-309

Comment: @FaceOfJock I'll take a look at the video too, already broke my deadline and I do not know, I'm desperate! hehehe, thanks for the tips, I'll check and give a better answer here later!

Answer (score 0):

I got it, first I did when I click a link step by GET and the ID Code I need after seto it in a cookie, each cookie with an ID. Then I check if cookie has registered with the IDs. Not the best and most correct, but it works (more or less). Now another problem, I need to click two times to get the result as it passes by id and need to be caught refresh = /

I think it was a bit confusing but it is the maximum that dyslexia allows me to do hehehe

Here I set up the structure with the data I have in my product page:

```
<a href="single-produtos.php?id_p=<?php echo $id_get;?>&cod=<?php echo $res->codigo; ?>">add</a>
<?php
    $cod_get = $_GET['cod'];
    setcookie("SITENAME_cod_".$id_get."", $cod_get, time()+3600, "/","", 0);
?>
```

And here I have a loop checking if cookie with ids, I think it will give problems, but for now I think it works ...

Thank you all.

```
$produto = new produtos();
$i = 0;
$produto->selecionaTudo($produto);
$produto->selecionaCampos($produto);
while($res = $produto->retornaDados()):
$res->id;
$i++;
$get_cookie = $_COOKIE['SITENAME_cod_'.$res->id.''];
if (isset($get_cookie)) {
  echo $get_cookie.', ';
}else{
  echo "";
}
endwhile;
```